# Filtering Mkoverlay array

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am trying to filter out arrays of MKOverlays using predicate but I am getting exception.

```
    NSArray *pointsArray = [viewController.mapView overlays];
    MKPolyline *myLine = (MKPolyline *)[pointsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray *mutablePonts = [pointsArray mutableCopy];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != TRIP"];
    [mutablePonts filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I want to filter out those overlays whose title is TRIP. I am getting exception

[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TRIP.

Comment: What is in your mutablePonts variable?

Comment: oops sorry, question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `TRIP`.

Comment: yes thanks I got it working by doing     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != %@",@"TRIP"];  :) thank you

Comment: No problem. =) This will do as well though: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != 'TRIP'"];`